# After i have upgraded to Android 4.0 ICS SDK, I can not find fastboot.exe tool

Tags: android, eclipse-plugin, android-ndk, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

After i have upgraded to Android 4.0 ICS SDK, I can not find fastboot.exe tool. Does anyone have any idea? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Fastboot wasn't included with r14 of the Android Tools release.  This is a [known issue](http://tools.android.com/knownissues#tools_r14), and there's a link on that page to the Tools r13 release, which you can use to grab fastboot in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

You can download fastboot.exe (as well as Linux version) from the HTC developers web site:
http://htcdev.com/bootloader/
Click "Unlock boot loader" button (registration required).

Also, you can download previous version of SDK and use fastboot.exe from there.